# Javascript (MooTools) window.addEvent('domready', function() { problems

Tags: javascript, html, mootools

My problem can be readily seen on the following to pages:

The correct version -> http://appstorereviewer.com/

The incorrect version -> http://appstorereviewer.com/page/2

As far as I can tell both pages have the same javascript in the header.  What would cause the main page to work properly and page/2 not to initialize?

Page 2 throws two errors:

1:

```
window.addEvent is not a function
[Break on this error] window.addEvent('domready', function() {\n
2 line 63
```

2:

```
RokTabsOptions is not defined
[Break on this error] RokTabsOptions.duration.push(50);\n
2 line 278
```

Please help

If I haven't provided enough information ask, I'll put more up!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 <script 
  type="text/javascript" 
  src="appstore/modules/mod_roktabs/tmpl/roktabs.js"></script>
```

This is a relative path. On the "correct" URL, it resolves to

```
http://appstorereviewer.com/appstore/modules/mod_roktabs/tmpl/roktabs.js
```

while the 'broken' one adds '/page/':

```
http://appstorereviewer.com/page/appstore/modules/mod_roktabs/tmpl/roktabs.js
```

This is a 404, so your 'tabs' code is never loaded. Add a leading slash to all of the  URLs to make the load from the docroot absolute path.

e.g.,

```
<script 
  type="text/javascript" 
  src="appstore/modules/mod_roktabs/tmpl/roktabs.js"></script>
```

becomes

```
<script 
  type="text/javascript" 
  src="/appstore/modules/mod_roktabs/tmpl/roktabs.js"></script>
```

Comment: Nice job, a second pair of eyes is always better.